# Zf2 custom annotation for AnnotationBuilder

Tags: angularjs, annotations, zend-framework2, zend-form

I need to create my own annotation to use it with the AnnotationBuilder.

This is to add the AngularJS directives using the something like

```
@AngularAnnotaion({"focuseMe"})
```

Because the default `Annotation\Attributes` dosn't allow me to add not pair argument, like `focoseMe` or `data-focuse-me`, only some kind of `data-ng-model":"location"`, that gave me the `data-ng-model="location"`.

Maybe some one can give the link to the example or some advice?

Comment: see my ans and let me know if that helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Zend does not support other attribute if that attribute start other than data-*

To enable Custom attibutes modify the view helper class as follows

1. Go to vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Form\View\Helper
2. Open AbstractHelper.php  class
3. Under this class you will see a method as prepareAttributes
4. change the following lines -

   ```
   if (!isset($this->validGlobalAttributes[$attribute])
      && !isset($this->validTagAttributes[$attribute])
     && 'data-' != substr($attribute, 0, 5)
   ) 

   to

    if (!isset($this->validGlobalAttributes[$attribute])
        && !isset($this->validTagAttributes[$attribute])
        && 'data-' != substr($attribute, 0, 5)
        && 'ng-' != substr($attribute, 0, 3)
     )
   ```

I have added  && 'ng-' != substr($attribute, 0, 3).

so you can use this in zf2 forms as follows

EX:-

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'pa_cat',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'attributes'    => array(
        'required'  => 'required',
        'class'     => 'styled_select pa_cat',  
        'ng-change' => 'test()',
        'options'   => array(
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array(
         'label'   => $plugin->z_xlt('Category')
    ),
 ));
```

you can use your own custom attribute using abstract helper class